# Code Signing Error with fastlane

Tags: code-signing, fastlane-match

I am getting error while building my application through fastlane. It gives me error that

> Code Signing Error: No profile for team '4TM2DK894Y' matching 'match
>   Development bundle-id' found:  Xcode couldn't find any provisioning
>   profiles matching '4TM2DK894Y/match Development bundle-id'.

I was able to do that but I ran the command mistakenly `fastlane match --readonly` and it installed new profiles and certificates I guess. After that I am continuously getting this error.
**While I am able to `archive` and `export` the build manually through Xcode.** 
Anyone has clue how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please could you share the part of your Fastfile which does the build?